# Multiplatform multiprocessing?

Tags: c++, process, c++11, pthreads, openmp

I was wondering why in the new C++11 they added threads and not processes.

Couldn't have they done a wrapper around platform specific functions?

Any suggestion about the most portable way to do multiprocessing? fork()? OpenMP?

Comment: Given that you have threads everywhere why not just pretend the threads are processes instead? There seems to be a misconception here too as the alternatives you suggested (pthreads and openmp) are both threads not processes. Are you perhaps mixing [threading models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Models) with processes?

Comment: @awoodland: ops, you are right, I meant the fork() family, not pthreads. I did not look at OpenMP, yet; from its name it seemed to be about multi processing.

Comment: OpenMP normally maps onto pthreads or whatever the system threading API is. OpenMPI will use processes or threads depending on the situation and hide that detail from you.

Comment: OpenMP is a standard for **shared memory multiprocessing**. Different processes in a single OS instance are isolated in their own VAs and thus are outside the scope of OpenMP. And for process-level multiprocessing there is already MPI with well established API - no need to reinvent the wheel or to make it square.

Comment: The *reason* for the minimal support is that the target date was 2008/2009 (C++0x, right?), and in that timeframe there just wasn't enough time for a more ambitious library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [Boost Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).

It does not provide the possibility to create new processes, but once they are there, it allows them to communicate.

In this particular case I can create the processes I need from a shell script.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this portably I'd suggest you avoid calling `fork()` directly and instead write your own library function that can be mapped on to a combination of `fork()` and `exec()` on systems where that's available. If you're careful you can make your function have the same or similar semantics as [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx) on Win32.

UNIX systems tend to have a quite different approach to processes and process management compared to Windows based systems so it's non-trivial to make all but the simplest wrappers portable.

Of course if you have C++11 or Boost available I'd just stick with that. If you don't have any globals (which is a good thing generally anyway) and don't set up and shared data any other way then the practical differences between threads and processes on modern systems is slim. All the threads you create can make progress independently of each other in the same way the processes can.

Failing that you could look at An MPI implementation if message passing suits your task, or a batch scheduler system.

Comment: "the practical differences between threads and processes on modern systems is slim" - Well, the fact that all threads share the same memory segment should be quite a fundamental difference, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Pietro - If each part of the address space is only touched by one thread then it's similar to having individual processes. The "background" to the statement you quoted though is that both `fork()` and `pthread_create()` map on to the same underlying system call (`clone()`) on Linux, so at one level they are indistinguishable. Even very traditional processes will have shared memory segments for the shared objects they load (mapped read/execute only).

Answer (score 3):

If you could use Qt, [`QProcess`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QProcess.html) class could be an elegant platform independent solution.